# Importing time module twice

Tags: python

I saw the code from Youtube and have a question.

The code below imports `time` twice.

1. import time
2. from time import mktime

---

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
```

By importing time on third line, I think 5th line is useless.

Why does he import time twice?

Comment: please look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229580/python-importing-a-sub-package-or-sub-module there is a nice answer there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does he import time twice?

He doesn't. He copies `time.mktime` to `mktime`. He doesn't have to, he just does so for convenience.