# Python error ' ModuleNotFoundError:'

Tags: python, importerror

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Exporter.py", line 3, in <module>
import sys,getopt,got,datetime,codecs
File "C:\Users\Rohil\Desktop\GetOldTweets-python-master\got\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
import models
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

my directory tree is:

```
C:\Users\Rohil\Desktop\GetOldTweets-python-master\got
```

this contains 2 folders: manager and models and 1 __init__.py file with the code :

```
import models
import manager
```

i am executing a file with the path: `C:\Users\Rohil\Desktop\GetOldTweets-python-master\Exporter.py`

I can't figure out what the issue is. can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\Rohil\Desktop\GetOldTweets-python-master\got` (how exactly, depends on your operating system)

Comment: can you import the other module? also, make sure that your terminal sees the correct PYTHONPATH value

Comment: created a new variable in windows called 'PythonPath' and added `C:\Users\Rohil\Desktop\GetOldTweets-python-master\got` as the value. Still throws the same error

Comment: nope, cant import any module from that folder. How do i make sure that the terminal sees the correct pythonpath value on windows?

Comment: the variable should be IN CAPITAL letters. then, at command prompt, try `echo %PYTHONPATH%` and check that you see the correct value

Comment: okay now, python sees the got folder, but refuses to see the files inside the models folder. Throws this error now : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Exporter.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sys,getopt,got,datetime,codecs
  File "C:\Users\Rohil\Desktop\GetOldTweets-python-master\got\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import models
  File "C:\Users\Rohil\Desktop\GetOldTweets-python-master\got\models\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Tweet import Tweet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tweet'`

Comment: Well, it worked so far, now you have a different problem than before, need more info. Also, make use that your __init__.py is empty file (does not import anything)

Answer (score 5):

If you have created a directory and sub-directory then follow the below steps and please keep in mind that a directory must have an `__init__.py` file for python to recognize it as a package.

1. First run this to see all paths being searched by python:

```py
import sys
sys.path
```

You must be able to see your current working directory in that list.

2. Now import the sub-directory and the respective module that you want to use via the `import` command: `import subdir.subdir.modulename as abc` You should now be able to use the methods in that module.

[image]

As you can see in this screenshot above I have one parent directory and two sub-directories. Under the second sub-directory I have a module named `CommonFunction`. On the console to the right you can see my working directory after execution of `sys.path`.

Comment: what if one of the path has a dot?

Answer (score 2):

- Does the `models` folder has an `__init__.py` file inside it ? Only then, it will be recognized as a module by python and `import models` would make sense.

So,

- Create an empty `__init__.py` file in the `models` subfolder and then the code should work without any issues.

You should also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12229742/6842947).

Comment: my models folder too has a \__init__.py file. Still gives the error

Comment: my models folder has a \__init__.py file which contains: `from Tweet import Tweet`

Answer (score -2):

if  create d or using or custom python package

check our dir. correct.

** For python 3.7 user **

```
from. import module_name
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using python3 but are installing the API through 'pip install 'such and such'. It's not gonna work on python3 console. Therefore, you'd better use 'sudo python3 -m pip install 'such and such''. Then it's gonna work!
(at least for ubuntu stuff)

:)

Comment: Thanks. Adding `sudo` to `python3 -m pip install "module_name"` helped to me.