# Import subfoldered python files as a folder (package), not as a module

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

Is it possible to call a function `gui.settings.load()` after `from ... import gui`? I am trying to set a folder like this.

```
main.py
gui/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
```

And in settings.py

```
def load():
    print('Hello')
```

In main.py

```
import gui

gui.settings.load()
```

Do I have to mess with `__init__.py`?

For now, I have to name the file `guiSettings.py` instead, which I want to make it more simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I really want to call `gui.settings.load()`, I might structure my directory like this.

```
main.py
src/
    __init__.py
    gui/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
```

In `main.py`

```
from src import *

gui.settings.load()
```

In `src/__init__.py`

```
from . import gui
```

In `src/gui/__init__.py`

```
from . import settings
```

In `src/gui/settings.py` is still as same as above.

It seems that putting `__all__ = ['gui']` and `__all__ = ['settings']` in respective `__init__.py` doesn't work, unless I am misunderstanding how `__all__` works.

Also, in this case `__init__.py` cannot be empty.

Also, it wouldn't work to just put `import *` without `from` in `main.py`.

Answer (score 0):

load according to your definition is not a function it is a class so yo can not call like this(class is meant to be instantiated you should review OOP cocepts). if you want to call function "load" you should define it as:

```
def load(parameters):
  #function body
  #optional return statement
```

and to interact with directories as modules e.i. using dot notation. the directory should include an `__init__.py` file. according to the docs:

> Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using
>   “dotted module names”. For example, the module name A.B designates a
>   submodule named B in a package named A.

Also:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages;

so in your case you should define `"__init__.py"` (possibly empty) inside the outter gui directory and in the inner gui directory. then inside the settings module you could define your load function as above. you can read more about packages and modules here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm

Comment: I find this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229580/python-importing-a-sub-package-or-sub-module but can I

from package import subpackage
print sub package.module ?

Comment: I have read your link but I could not understand your question. @Polv

Comment: Succeeded, by putting import gui.settings inside `__init__.py` and it somehow doesn't work with an empty `__init__`. Also, I cannot seem to use the filename `gui/gui.py`

Comment: Congratulation, you may import all modules in init.py and then you only have to import the containing package to use the modules, but this is unrecommended.

Comment: So, `gui.settings.load()` should generally mean `gui.py` with class `settings` and function-in-class `load`? Not `settings.py`?

Comment: It means (if I have Interpreted your question correctly) call the function named load (e.i. execute it) that reside in the settings.py module that in turn reside in the gui package.