# python3 module import from subpackage

Tags: python, import, module

Let's assume I do have such package structure:

```
foobar/
    - foo/bar.py
    - ...
    main.py
```

Shall I use:

```
from foo import bar
```

or

```
import foo.bar
```

or

```
import foo.bar as bar
```

Currently, I do `from foo import bar` as I find it correct but I want to double check it (I think Python documentation recommends this also).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: importing a sub‑package or sub‑module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229580/python-importing-a-sub-package-or-sub-module)

Comment: Yes, correct as it is possible duplicate but I do not find one line answer in that question. Probably 'from subpackage import module' is the answer but I wonder what ppl think about 'import subpackage.module' if it is wrong or not.