# Conditionally modify import statements

Tags: python

I have a collection of .py files in the following file structure:

```
packagename\
    mod_1.py
    mod_2.py
    script_1.py
    etc.
```

These files do two things:

1. They're bundled into an application (a JMP/JSL add-in, although not relevant here).  In this application `script_1.py` is called, and it contains import statements like `import mod_1`.  `mod_1.py` in turn imports `mod_2.py` as `import mod_2`.  This is fine.
2. The files are also bundled up into a python package called `packagename`.  In this context when I want to import `mod_2.py` inside `mod_1.py` I call `import packagename.mod_2`.  This is also fine.

I presently implement this in `mod_1.py`, very painfully, as:

```
if 'addin' in __file__:
    import mod_2
else:
    import packagename.mod_2
```

This works but I've got lots and lots of modules (more than just mod_1, mod_2).  Is there a way to do something like this (pseudocode)?:

```
if 'addin' in __file__:
    import_prefix = ''
else:
    import_prefix = 'packagename.'

import import_prefix + mod_2
```

This answer seems to cover half of what I'm looking for, but not everything:
[Python: importing a sub‑package or sub‑module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229580/python-importing-a-sub-package-or-sub-module)

Comment: Maybe you can use `importlib` to write a function that does this, so you just call the function instead of writing repeated `if` statements.

Comment: `script_1.py` may be part of your *distribution* package, but it should not be part of the *import* package that contains `mod_1.py` and `mod_2.py`. The script should use `import packagename.mod_1`, with the script and package installed appropriately in each scenario.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import module from string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)

Comment: Better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-its-name-as-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just want to use `importlib.import_module`.

```
import importlib

def _import(module_name: str):
    if 'addin' in __file__:
        return importlib.import_module(module_name)
    return importlib.import_module(f'packagename.{module_name}')

mod_2 = _import(mod_2)
```